# Android fragment :should back to fresh page

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have two fragment A and B. 
 Fragment A : have 1 view, i scroll view  bottom. after move fragment B, touch back at fragment B move fragment A, i want to see  view have scroll top(same refresh layout fragment A. when onCreate).

My view : NewHeader, PullToRevealListView, button search and FrameLayout is parent

Answer (score 0):

Use this function to inflate your first fragment i.e call this function in onCreateView of fragment A

```
public View createPersistentView(LayoutInflater inflater,
            ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState, int layout) {
        if (_rootView == null) {

            _rootView = inflater.inflate(layout, null);
        } else {

            ((ViewGroup) _rootView.getParent()).removeView(_rootView);
        }

        return _rootView;
    }
```